# How can I set a class property in 1 method and call it in another?

Tags: c#

Trying to create a method to store data with and use another method to call the data.

I have banged my head at the wall and im down to just 1 error now. 
main.cs(10,1): error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `MainClass.Test()'
main.cs(12,24): error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member`MainClass.Car.Name'
**strong text**
using System;

```
using System;

class MainClass
{
    class Gear
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string Rod
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string Reel
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string Line
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public int CastDistance
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    private static Gear gearinstance;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test();
        Console.WriteLine(gearInstance.Name);
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter your Name: ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        gearInstance = new Gear
         {
            Name = name;
        };

    }
}
```

Explained earlier but want it to call the class from multiple methods

Comment: You'd want to declare a `static Car car` outside of your `Main`, so that `Test` can access it. You'd also want to _call_ `Test`.

Comment: You're creating two instances of Car. They have nothing to do with each other. They're not the same object. If you set Name on one, that has nothing to do with the other one. Each has its own value for `Name`. This is why you need Rufus' solution.

Comment: @Sweeper I want to set the Value of name in Test and call it in Main, will that be possible? sorry I am very much a novice in c#

Comment: @crapcoder Rufus L's answer should do the job.

Comment: Thank you :-) I see it now I missed it at first

Answer (score 0):

Variables declared inside a method are local to that method. If you want to share an instance of something between methods in a class, make that object a member of the class (either a private field as below, or as a property):

```
class MainClass
{
    class Car
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    // This static instance will be shared amongst the static methods
    private static Car carInstance;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test();
        Console.WriteLine(carInstance.Name);
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        carInstance = new Car { Name = "Chevrolet Corvette" };
        Console.WriteLine("This is a test");
    }
}
```